# How to fix/diagnose GUI issues on Ubuntu 18.04/18.10?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, gnome, graphics

For the past few weeks, there have been some issues with the GUI lately. I believe these issues started when I installed CUDA 9.0.

**My machine:**

- GPU: GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile + Intel HD Graphics
- OS: Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish

**GUI Issues**:

1. When switching to tty1 and logging in, the login screen's mouse
   cursor is still there (doesn't occur anymore)
2. Sometimes the, when I try to lock the screen, the display freezes on the Desktop and then a glitch occurs: the system menu keeps showing up multiple times on top of each other)
3. When I login, the screen flashes a couple of times and lags a bit
   before rendering the desktop (I believe this is because of a new TTY is starting up for X Server, although it doesn't happen when I switch to Intel Graphics from NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles)
4. Sometimes when I logout and try to login, a "login loop" occurs where the I enter the password and the login screen keeps showing up instead of the desktop (I have to use chmod on .Xauthority to login)
5. When I lock the screen, and close the lid (suspend) then open it again, I find myself logged out.

At first I had Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I thought if I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10, these issues would be fixed but nothing happened.

**Other things I tried:**

1. Reinstalled the NVIDIA drivers
2. Uncommented WaylandEnable=false line in '/etc/gdm3/custom.conf'
3. Switched to LightDM (new issues occured so I switched back to GDM3)
4. Reinstalled GNOME and GDM3
5. Reinstalled X Server (using apt install --reinstall)

Is there any way to further diagnose/fix this problem? The only solution I'm thinking of is to install Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I've noticed that the root of all my problems with NVIDIA drivers is performing a `apt upgrade` before or after I installed the drivers. NVIDIA will automatically upgrade to the exact linux kernel it needs, and then don't touch it after that

Answer (score 0):

Try using this repo: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

And try this. Enable root for convenience: `sudo -i`; enter your password then

```
apt remove nvidia* --purge -y
apt remove wayland -y
apt autoremove
add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
apt update
apt upgrade --fix-missing
apt install nvidia-driver-410 -f -y
apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop -f -y
```

And (seemingly always) with Nvidia you'd want to add `nouveau.modeset=0` to your GRUB. Have you been checking your system log for anything peculiar?

Comment: By system log, are you referring to the dmesg output?

Comment: `/var/log/syslog`
Alternatively you can use the SystemLog GUI